# No setPageMargin() in Android

Tags: android, view, margin, pager

Ive been trying to use the setPageMargin to set the margins between different views in a view pager.

First I do this:

```
pager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpagerlayout);
```

And then,

```
pager.setPageMargin(5);
```

But I get an error saying the method is not found. I have also added support libraries to the project, and its still nothing.

Please help.

Comment: How have you declared the `pager` variable?

Comment: Ive used ViewPager pager;

Comment: And your `import`s correctly import `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager` and not some other class of the same name?

Comment: Actually I couldnt find the import. I had to explicitly add it. It still didnt help. I get an error saying- "setPageMargin is undefied for type ViewPager".

Comment: Ah sorry. The import was present. I just overlooked it previously.

Comment: Hi @laalto. I got to work. I hadnt installed the support libraries correctly. Thanks for your efforts anyway! :)

Comment: HI @Anirudh, I'm having the same issue. Can I ask what you mean by installing the support libraries correctly?